# Keep set -e setting inside || or &&

Tags: error-handling, sh, posix

I have a simple script with a simple function which can lead to an error. Let's define this function, and make it broken:

```
brokenFunction () {
    ls "non-existing-folder"
}
```

If we execute this function in a block detecting if it is broken, it works well:

```
brokenFunction || printf "It is broken\n"
```

prints "It is broken"

Now, let's make the function a bit more complex, by adding a correct command at the end :

```
#!/bin/sh

brokenFunction () {
    ls "non-existing-folder"
    printf "End of function\n"
}

brokenFunction || printf "It is broken\n"
```

This script prints :

```
$ ./script.sh 
ls: cannot access 'non-existing-folder': No such file or directory
End of function
```

while I expected the function to stop before the printf statement, and the next block to display "It is broken".

And indeed, if I check the exit status code of `brokenFunction`, it is 0.

I tried adding `set -e` to the top of the script. The behavior is still the same, but the exit code of `brokenFunction` if called without `||` now becomes `2`. If called with it, the status code is still `0`.

Is there any way to keep the `set -e` setting inside a function called with `||`?

EDIT: I just realized that the function in the example was useless. I encounter the same issue with a simple block and a condition.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
{
    ls "non-existing-dir"
    printf "End of block\n"
} || {
    printf "It is broken\n"
}
```

prints

```
$ ./script.sh 
ls: cannot access 'non-existing-dir': No such file or directory
End of block
```

Comment: I found why it does not work as expected: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside Now, I'm just looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in `man bash`, `set -e` is ignored in some contexts. A command before `||` or `&&` is such a context.

`trap` looks like a possible solution here. A working alternative to the last script using `trap` would look like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
abort () {
    printf "It is broken\n"
}
trap 'abort' ERR
(
    set -e
    false
    printf "End of block\n"
)
trap - ERR
```

Some things have to be noticed here:

- `trap 'abort' ERR` binds the `abort` function to any raised error ;
- the broken block is executed in a sub-shell for 2 reasons. First is to keep the set -e setting inside the block and limit the border effects. Second is to exit this sub-shell on error (`set -e` effect), and not the whole script ;
- `trap - ERR` at the end resets the `trap` binding, meaning the following part of the script is executed as before.

To test the border effects, we can add the previously non-working part :

```
#!/bin/sh
abort () {
    printf "It is broken\n"
}

trap 'abort' ERR
(
    set -e
    false
    printf "End of block\n"
)
trap - ERR

{   
    false
    printf "End of second block\n"
} || {
    printf "It is broken too\n"
}
```

prints:

```
It is broken
End of second block
```

Comment: `trap ERR` is not POSIX. I should probably change it to `trap EXIT` with the `set -e` parameters.